# Set cookies using flask-restx

Tags: python, flask, cookies, flask-jwt-extended, flask-restx

Is there a way to set cookies using `flask-restx`? I'm using it in combination with `flask-jwt-extended` and I would like to have an endpoint that sets the jwt-cookie.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
@namespace.route("/login")
class Login(Resource):
    @namespace.expect(login_model)
    def post(self):
        data = namespace.payload
        username = data.get("username")
        password = data.get("password")

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            return {"message": "Unauthorized"}, 401

        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user, fresh=True)

        response = jsonify()
        set_access_cookies(response, access_token)
        return response, 200
```

I get the following Error when sending a request to `/login`:

```
TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
```

The code works as expected when switching out the `response` in the return value for a `{}`, so the problem seems to be that `flask-restx` doesn't support returning a `Response` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what went wrong. When returning a `Response` directly, you must not add a status code. The resulting code looks like this:

```py
@namespace.route("/login")
class Login(Resource):
    @namespace.expect(login_model)
    def post(self):
        data = namespace.payload
        username = data.get("username")
        password = data.get("password")

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            return {"message": "Unauthorized"}, 401

        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user, fresh=True)

        response = jsonify()
        set_access_cookies(response, access_token)
        return response
```